# How do template reference variables work when the variable name is reused?

Tags: angular, scope

How do template reference variables work when the variable name is reused? What are the scoping rules when referring to such a variable from within the template?

Answer (score 2):

The variable is available within the template.
If you reuse it you'll get an error message.

If you use it for elements created by `*ngFor` (or some other structural directive like `*ngIf` or some other way to stamp templates), then the scope is within that template and can't be accessed from outside, but also don't conflict with each other.